# Nested fields in form is not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Im new to ruby on rails so i need some tips please.

Im trying to render some checkboxes on the edit view for a user.
I have tried to follow the documentation for the nested_attributes but the checkboes does not render.
Here is the relation between the two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :softwares
  has_many :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :softwares
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses
```

The Edit view for a user

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
      <%= form_for @student, url: auth_student_path(@student), method: :put do |f| %>
      

         <div class="col-md-12 mb-5 mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="mb-3 filter_heading">Softwares</h3>
            

            <% @softwares.each do |sf|%>
              <%= f.fields_for :softwares do |software| %>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="courses">
                    <%= software.label sf.title %>
                    <%= software.check_box :title, {multiple: true}, sf.title, nil %>
                  </div>

                 <% sf.courses.each do |crs|%>
                    <%= f.fields_for :courses do |course|%>
                      <div class="mt-1 courses-checkbox">
                          <%= course.label crs.name %>
                          <%= course.check_box :name, {multiple: true}, crs.name , nil %>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end%>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            <% end%>
          </div>
         

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Controller

```
module Auth
    class StudentsController < ApplicationController
        before_action :authenticate_user!
        before_action :set_student, only: %i[delete_certificates]

        def edit
            authorize! :edit, @user
            @softwares = Software.all
            @student = User.find(params[:id])
        end

        def update
            authorize! :update, @user
            @student = User.find(params[:id])

            if @student.update(student_params)               
                redirect_to edit_auth_student_path(@student)
            else               
                redirect_to edit_auth_student_path(@student)
            end
        end

        def show


        def set_student
            @student = User.find(params[:student_id])
        end

        private
    
        def student_params
            params.require(:user).permit(
              :email,
              :firstname,
              :lastname,
              :phone,
              :locked,
              :approved,
              :role,
              badges: [],
              certificates: [],
              softwares_attributes: [:title],
              courses_attributes: [:name],
            )
          end
    end
end
```

Please help me.

Comment: A heads up - software is uncountable so the proper plural is *software*.  This code will work since rails doesn't have a proper inflection set up but may cause developer confusion.

Comment: To answer the specific question of why `f.fields_for :softwares` isn't actually rendering anything its because you haven't actually assigned anything to `@student.softwares`. `fields_for` loops through the assocation and if there is nothing to loop through then nothing happens. You're really just using it very wrong here though.

Comment: @max The problem here is that when students are created the dont have any belonging Softwares. Its only the Admin that can update the student on what Softwares he/she  has completed. So the check boxes in the students Edit vie must be visible. Thats why i cant use `@studen.softwares` in the edit view, because initially the Student dosent have any Softwares.

Comment: @max Alos if i use `f.fields_for :software` (not `f.fields_for :softwares`) the checkboxes will appear but i get unpermitted params in the controller

Comment: And the admin must be able to create new Softwares and Courses.

Comment: Thats last part is really a completely different concern and would be handled in a separate controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` just to select existing records and associate them with something. Its only needed if you need to create/update the other record (the course or software) at the same time.

I'm also guessing you don't actually want to have a one-to-many assocation and duplicate every course and every software for each user - instead you want a many to many assocation and some [data normalization](https://blog.insycle.com/normalize-data).

So create a join table to hold the assocation between users and courses for example:

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments, foreign_key: :student_id
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments
end

# rails g model enrollment student:belongs_to course:belongs_to
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, through: :enrollments
end
```

And then you just create inputs that use the `course_ids` / `course_ids=` setter and getter created by `has_many :courses, through: :enrollments`.

```ruby
<%= form_with(model: @student, url: auth_student_path(@student), method: :put) do |f| %> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :course_ids, 'Select your courses' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :course_ids, @courses, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
  </div>

  # ...
<% end %>
```

And then you just whitelist an array of ids in your controller:

```
params.require(:user)
      .permit(
        # ...
        course_ids: []
      )
```

In fact if your ever passing existing records as anything but an ID you're doing it **very wrong**.

There are still plenty of issues with this code but this should at least be nudge in the correct direction.